# Is a finite set of probability distributions a subset of the set of all probability distributions over itself?

Tags: probability

I am currently trying to write something but I got stuck. Essentially, I need to know whether a finite set of probability distributions is a subset of the set of all probability distributions over itself.

Let me put my problem formally. Let $X$ be an arbitrary finite set, and let $D(X)$ be the set of all probability distributions over the set $X$: namely,
\begin{gather}
D(X)=\left\{d\in[0,1]^X\mid\sum_{x\in X}d(x)=1\right\}
\end{gather}

Further, let $\Theta\subsetneq D(X)$ be any finite subset of $D(X)$. Then, let $\Delta(\Theta)$ be the set of all probability distributions over the set $\Theta$: namely,
\begin{gather}
\Delta(\Theta)=\left\{\delta\in[0,1]^\Theta\mid\sum_{\theta\in\Theta}\delta(\theta)=1\right\}
\end{gather}

**QUESTION: is it correct to say that $\Theta\subseteq \Delta(\Theta)$?**

A part of me believes it is correct, for $\Theta$ and $\Delta(\Theta)$ are the same type of set; however, another part of me suspects it is not correct, but I can't pinpoint why. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: No?  An element of $\Theta$ is a distribution on $X$.  An element of $\Delta(\Theta)$ is a distribution on the finite set $\Theta$, which isn't $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. It would be akin to saying $X \subseteq D(X)$ or the set {head, tail} is a subset of all possible coin-toss distributions (whether fair or not fair).